# Ubuntu will not try to boot

Tags: boot, 20.04

Running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Ryzen 1700, while booting, after the BIOS message it will sit there without loading, there is no loading circle or Ubuntu logo. I am not running dual boot, I have only been able to get into GRUB once and haven’t been able to since

Comment: Hi James. Are you able to boot from a Live pendrive?

Comment: Yes I can boot from it

Comment: Verify that the live usb is good and reinstall.

Comment: Hi James. please follow the steps that I will post to allow grub to give you the chance to boot from previos kernels.

Comment: (keep in mind that it is not the final solution but a step to dig into the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to try to boot from another kernel:
(keep in mind that it is not the final solution but a step to dig into the problem)

> 1. Boot from live usb (try ubuntu)
> 2. Open a terminal and as root (sudo -s) mount your boot partition in /mnt
>    example: "mount /dev/sdax /mnt".
> 3. execute chroot /mnt
>    When you do chroot now your / starts from what was mounted in /mnt.
> 4. edit your grub settings
>    the suggested way to do this is by modifying /etc/default/grub
>    on this file change this line to "GRUB_TIMEOUT=15" (this will allow you to see grub menu)
> 5. execute update-grub
> 6. reboot

After reboot in Grub menu choose advanced options for Ubuntu and try another Kernel (let say 5.8.x)

Whit this step will be able to dig on the next steps.

Also, I recommend you to install grub customizer and set the boot option to previously booted. This can also be achieved by replacing the line

> GRUB_DEFAULT="saved"

in the grub configuration.

Good luck.